# money system using localstorage in html

Tags: javascript

I want my page to be able to do following:
There is a "money" value when the user enters the page, and there are things to buy. When the user clicks to buy something, it deducts from that 15$ (I have already scripted this), but when you refresh the page it resets to 15$.

How do I make it stay at the value that it was depending on how much the user spent even after refreshing, and so that I can edit the html to put any value of money again? I tried localstorage but I don't seem to get it to work.

```
var money= 15;
if (money >= 2) {
  snd.play();
  //the first statement should generate a random number in the range 0 to 6 (the subscript values of the image file names in the imagesArray)
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21); // 0...6
  //the second statement display the random image from the imagesArray array in the canvas image using the random number as the subscript value
  document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
  money=money-2;
  document.getElementById("wallet").innerHTML = money;
  alert.style.display = "block";

  span.onclick = function() {
     alert.style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == alert) {
        alert.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
} else {
    alert("Payment was not recieved: Insufficient funds.");
}
}
```

This is a function I want to work like I described, but with local storage instead of just `money=money-2`.

Comment: I've reformatted your code - but there is an unatched '}'

Comment: " i tried localstorage but i dont seem to get it to work" - not in the code you've shown here.

Comment: Thanks for trying man, my codes are always a mess lol

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `LocalStorage` it's really [quite simple to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

To set a value:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

To get that value:

```
localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

So what you could do on your page load is get the money from the local storage, use that if it exists, if it doesn't exist save a new 'starting' value to the local storage.